# Facebook Scraper seeing only parts of header

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I couldn't see an obvious reason for the differences, but am pretty new to coding for facebook friendliness.

I've got a page on my site that shows flickr albums:
http://jpgme.co.uk/sports/index.php?type=sets

At the moment the headers source looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Blue Line Ice Hockey Photography - Professional Ice Hockey Photography in Greater Manchester & Beyond</title>
    <link href='http://jpgme.co.uk/sports/themes/blackstripe/css/blackstripe.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel='alternate' type='application/rss+xml' title='Blue Line Ice Hockey Photography - Professional Ice Hockey Photography in Greater Manchester & Beyond' href='http://jpgme.co.uk/sports/index.php?type=rss' />

    <meta property="fb:admins" content="61401353" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Blue Line Ice Hockey Photography" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://jpgme.co.uk/sports/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://jpgme.co.uk/images/fb.jpg"/>

</head>
```

But all the facebook scraper can see is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>
<div id="leftcontent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying scrapping after document load!

The possible reason is that you are trying to scrap before the whole page load.

Moreover FB using AJAX adds/removes the div as and when required, that can also be the possible problem.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't being patient enough.

[link]https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fjpgme.co.uk%2Fsports%2Findex.php%3Ftype%3Dsets
[/link]
Now shows everything correctly